# Why do I see two different versions of TypeScript with ng -v and tsc -v? How can force VSCode to use older version i.e. 2.6.2?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

[Why do I see two different versions of TypeScript with ng -v and tsc -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4nOB.png)

Comment: tsc is the version of the typescript compiler

Comment: @Sachin - and the one I see with ng -v ? whats that ? I see 2.9.2 with ng -v and 2.6.2 with tsc -v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `npm install typescript@"2.4.2" --save` in you project folder. That should install the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng v` or `ng version` show you which version of `Typescript` your `Angular CLI` actually use.

And using `tsc -v` show you which version of the `Typescript` compiler run actually on your machine.

Comment: thanks billyjov. any idea on how to resolve ng build warning -  @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.11 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0' but 2.9.2 was found instead